# Is request rate throttling ok for ad bots?

Tags: advertising, user-agent, crawl-rate, throttling, bidding

We're using a header-bidding partner for our website, so we're serving ads from multiple demand partners. A lot of these partners have their bots and so our website is getting accessed by them pretty frequently, but that's ok. What is a problem though is that some of these bots tend to be pretty intrusive and are causing a pretty high server load by doing 10+ requests per second at times. It's not even constant. It almost always starts exactly at 1:30 AM UTC, and takes 15-45 minutes to finish. Other than that, the server is running at like 50% load all the time.

So the solution seems pretty obvious - rate throttling. Not dropping any requests, just throttle them to a tolerable rate for our server. We found out that when we throttle all User Agents containing `bot`, `spider` or `crawl` (with exclusions) to 5r/s per User-Agent (so that every bot has it's own limit), our server doesn't experience those huge load peaks anymore. We put the limit only on content served dynamically (Django), not any of our media / static files.

Can we be sure that won't affect our ad performance? Is 5r/s enough? Do those bots need to see the site before delivering ads to our users? Are those requests time-sensitive for them, or are they just caching the content after ads got already served? We really wouldn't like this to affect our ad loading speed / performance in any way.

Any input will be highly appreciated! :)

The nginx config we put in place:

```
map $http_user_agent $django_bots_limit_key {
  default "";
  ~*(google|apple|yahoo|msn|duckduck|bing|baidu|yandex|alexa|pinterest|facebook|twitter|reddit|slack|discord|pingdom|semrush) "";
  ~*(bot|crawl|spider|weborama|ias-va) $http_user_agent;
}

limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=django:10m rate=5r/s;
limit_req_zone $django_bots_limit_key zone=django_bots:30m rate=5r/s;

location / {
  limit_req zone=django burst=100 delay=4;
  limit_req zone=django_bots burst=100 delay=4;
}
```

Comment: 5 req/sec is really low I'd say. Just look at any popular website and see how many requests are made for a single page... its typically over 100.